# Exclude specific files in Sonar's analyse

Tags: sonarqube

First my Sonarqube version is 4.5.2.
I want to exclude from analyze two files : `fr.foo.foo1.MyClass1` and `fr.foo.foo1.MyClass2`, there is another classes in the foo1 package that I want still in the anlyse.

I try to set in the tab exclusions/files : exclude sources : `**/fr/foo/foo1/MyClass1.java` and `**/fr/foo/foo1/MyClass2.java` but the classes still in the analyse.

the only way I find to exclude the classes is to set the parameter to `**/fr/foo/foo1/**` but all the classes in the package are excluded or I want only the two classes MyClass1 and MyClass2.

The image below show how I set the exclusion in Sonar : 
[image]

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Stef

Comment: Could you provide the exact field value when you set it to the two classes individually?

Comment: Hello, I add a snapshot to my post to illustrate the field value